# How to hide dom element for App when loading another component

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that uses a menu to navigate between screens. The main class is named "App" and the others are "Add", "Edit", and "List". When I click an item from the menu, the appropriate screen (class) displays, and the menu and heading from the "App" remain. This allows navigation from the "children" screens also.

The problem that I have is that I want to hide the heading "h3" className "appHeader" from the "App" because it interfers with the  heading from the other screens.

How can I do that?

The render code from "App" is below:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="menu">
            <ul>
              <li><Link to="/">Home </Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/add">Add</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/list">List</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/add' component={Add} />
              <Route exact path='/edit/:id' component={Edit} />
              <Route exact path='/list' component={List} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter >
        <h3 className="appHeader">ToDo App</h3><br />
        <h3 className="warning">{this.state.warningMsg}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best or only way, but this appears to be solved by the following:

In "App":

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact path='/add'
            render={(props) => <Add {...props}
              changeHeader={this.changeHeader} />} />

  <h3 className="appHeader">{this.state.headerText}</h3>
```

The function as follows can then be run from the component loaded via the props:

```
changeHeader(text) { this.setState({
      headerText: text ? "Todo App - " + text : "Todo App"
    });
  }
```

In "Add":

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.changeHeader("Add");
  }
```